# XCode4: does the contents of a workspace contain everything?

Tags: xcode4

I have two projects in a workspace, which I have under SVC (Subversion control), using the feature in XC4 .  My question is:  does the repository contain EVERYTHING that is in the workspace, including all of the source (classes, etc) for both of the projects?

Or is the source files kept on my local hard drive?  (the repository is on a BeanStalk server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the repository contains depends on how you imported the projects to the repository. You can see what files the repository contains by opening the Organizer. Select the Root folder for your BeanStalk repository from the repository list, and the Organizer shows the files and folders that are in the repository.

To answer your second question, the source files on your hard drive are most likely a working copy that you checked out from the BeanStalk server.